Problem with Length command
I am using the Length[] for counting number of additive terms. It works fine but when I have the following type of terms
expr = 1/x (-(4/3) \[Pi]^2 G[0, 0, -1, -1, x] + 
     1/6 \[Pi]^2 G[0, 0, -1, 0, x] + 3 + H[0, 0, x] + 
     j[C2, 0, 0, x]);
Length[expr]

it counts the multiplicative terms, rather additive one, and the answer turns out to be 2, but should be 5.
I do not want to use Simplify[], Expand[] etc, since I am using for very long expressions and also I need the soln for general purpose use.
One of my try is
In[46]:= (
 1/3 \[Pi]^2 G[0, 0, -1, x] - G[0, 0, -1, 0, -1, x] + 
  G[0, 0, -1, 0, 0, x] + G[0, 0, 0, 0, -1, x] - 
  G[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, x])/x /. Times[x__*y__] :> y

Out[46]= 1/3 \[Pi]^2 G[0, 0, -1, x] - G[0, 0, -1, 0, -1, x] + 
 G[0, 0, -1, 0, 0, x] + G[0, 0, 0, 0, -1, x] - G[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, x]


it works well, but then when I have complicated multiplicative factor, it does not provide correct result:
In[56]:= (168/x (1 + x)^3 (H[0, 0, 1, x] + 2) /. Times[x__*y__] :> y)

Out[56]= Sequence[1/x, (1 + x)^3, 2 + H[0, 0, 1, x]]
```


If you type TreeForm[expr] you will see the type of the expression is Times since that is the root of the tree, with 2 leaves.  I do not see where the 3 length comes from for +. Looking at the tree, the right leave is rooted at + and that has 5 leaves below it not 3.

Select[expr,Head[#]==Plus&];  Length[%]  gives 5

Your expression is (value in parentheses)/x which is a length of 2.  If you want the length of the value in parentheses, use Length[expr[[2]]] which gives 5.  I'm not where your length of 3 comes from.

Sorry, 3 was a typo, it should return the output 5

Select[expr,Head[#]==Plus&]; works perfectly. Thanks

I see one issue: when the input is expr = 1/x (H[0, 0, 1, x]), it provides output zero.

Because there is no Plus there. That's why zero. Your question is rather vague. For example, what is "the number of additive terms" of (a+b)/(c+d)? If you can describe the structure of your expression more systematically, then you can get more useful answers to your goal.

If you have expressions such as e+(a+(b+(c+d)))*8 what should the number of additive terms be?  TreeForm shows there are two Plus terms. So you want the answer to be 2 in this case or something else?

How many terms do you expect for In[56]? Is it 2 or 8? If it's 8, then I don't see a way of getting around using Expand, because you need to expand the (1+x)^3. If the answer should be 2, then we need more information, because you need to establish criteria for when and when not to expand factors. Length@Numerator@expr works for your first example but will not work in general. Perhaps some modification of it will work.
